# What will be the value of variable thisconnection and HOW?

Tags: javascript

```
var connections = {key: 1234}
var thisconnection = connections["key"] || {status:"new"};`
```

In the above code, the variable thisconnection is subjected to the Logical operator `'||'`

When I simply type the following code in the console, `thisconnection` takes the value of the `connections["key"]` in any case.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Since there's a value for connections["key"] the result of the conditional will be its value. If the wasn't, it'd end up being the anonymous object with a "status" key/value.

Comment: The answers below give you an explanation, however the line of code itself is a bit odd, as you are setting the value to either an integer or an object.  More often than not you would expect both options to be of the same type so they could be used consistently further on through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following statement

```
var thisconnection = connections["key"] || {status:"new"};
```

You are saying if `connection["key"]` exists assign `connection["key"]` to `thisconnection`, other wise assign `{status:new}` to `thisconnection`.

It's same as following code

```
if(connections["key"]){
    thisconnection = connection["key"]
}
else{
    thisconnection = {status:new}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try it?

```
var connections = {key: 1234};
var thisconnection = connections["key"] || {status:"new"};
console.log(thisconnection); // returns 1234
```

Explanation:

If `connections.key` returned 0, NaN, false, undefined, "" (empty string), or any value that evaluated to false, it would continue evaluating the next `||` expression.

However, if the expression evaluates to a truthy value, the whole statement is finished with evaluation. This is known as [*short-circuiting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation):

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.

Since `1234` is a truthy value, evaluation stops and the value 1234 is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

if `connections["key"]` is nil then `{status:"new"}` will be the value of variable

Answer (score 1):

First it will check `connections["key"]`,

If it is not null, then the value of `thisconnection` with contain value of `connections["key"]`. Otherwise `thisconnection` will contain value of `{status:"new"}`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `||` and `&&` operators have a specific behavior when used in variable assignment. If you have something like this:

```
var theResult = a || b || c || d;
```

Then, the variable `theResult` won't be a boolean as we expect in other languages.

If `a` is truhty, then `theResult = a`. Else, if `b` is truhty, then `theResult = b`. And so on... If all variables are falsy, then `theResult = d` because `d` is the last statement in the or condition.

The rule is the following:

the value of `theResult` will be the value of the variable in `a || b || c || d` which break the chain

So, since we have only OR conditions, then the first value which resolve to `true` will break the chain. I mean, if `a === true`, then it's not needed to evaluate the rest of the condition because `true || false || whatEver || weDontCare` will always be `true`. If none of the variable breaks the chain, then the last variable is assigned to `theResult`.